# having issue in fetching multiline record from oracle to unix

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am fetching data from Oracle to UNIX flat file. For one column there is a record which is having new line character.
Ex: Oracle table

```
ID   Comment            Date
1    my name **\n**     1111/11/11
     is **\n**
     abc
2    second comment     1111/11/11
```

when i am fetching this type of record using SQLPlus on UNIX every newline is going in different line.

Please see example below.

**Unix file:**

```
ID|    Comment   |Date
 1|my name**\n** |1111/11/11 
 |is **\n**|
 |abc|
 2|second comment|1111/11/11
```

How can I fetch those records in UNIX flat file as single row instead of 3 separate rows?

**Using below code in shell script:**

```
sqlplus -s userid/password@database << EOF > abc.txt
set colsep |
set echo off;
set heading on;
set feedback off;
set pagesize 0 embedded on;
set linesize 10000;
SET trims ON;
set trimspool on;
@abc.sql
exit;
EOF
```

I want my result in below format in UNIX file. Please suggest.

```
ID|    Comment   |Date
 1|my name is abc|1111/11/11
 2|second comment|1111/11/11
```